# Mapping classes with dependent objects to separate tables in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have an entity class Order which has attributes orderID, customerName and an Item ArrayList. Item is another entity class in my application which has a separate table. Item table has a composite primary key of ProductID and OrderID. OrderID is a foreign key referring to OrderID in order table. Whenever I save an order i want all the attributes of order instance should be saved in order table except the Items. Items which are in the ArrayList must be saved in a separate rows in the item table with the orderID. How to achieve this. I am quite new to hibernate so please give me a detailed answer and if I am doing something wrong please correct me. Thanks in advance.